# Merging an array of objects without overwriting

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, treeview

I am currently with some JSON, which has to be structured in a tree-like hierarchy. The depth of the hierarchy varies a lot, and is therefor unknown.

As it is right now, I have achieved to get an array of objects. Example is below.

```json
[
    {
      "name": "level1",
      "collapsed": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Level 1 item here",
          "id": 360082134191
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "level1",
      "collapsed": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "level2",
          "collapsed": true,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Level 2 item here",
              "id": 360082134751
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "level1",
      "collapsed": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Another level 1 item",
          "id": 360082262772
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

What I want to achieve is these objects to be merged, without overwriting or replacing anything. Listed below is an example of how I want the data formatted:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "level1",
    "collapsed": true,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "level2",
        "collapsed": true,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Level 2 item here",
            "id": 360082134751
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 1 item here",
        "id": 360082134191
      },
      {
        "name": "Another level 1 item",
        "id": 360082262772
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How would I achieve this with JavaScript? No libraries is preferred, ES6 can be used though.

**Edit:**
It is important that the output is an array, since items without children can appear at the root.

Comment: why does `"Level 1 item here"` comes later than `"level2"`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I'm assuming you're merging on `name`.  What do you expect if nodes you're trying to merge have different `collapsed` values?

Comment: @ScottSauyet That would not be a problem, as this is the initial structure, and therefore it will always be false! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you need a little help on working with the data. There could be multiple ways to achieve this, here is how would I do.

```
// data => supplied data
const result = data.reduce ((acc, item) => {
  // if acc array already contains an object with same name,
  // as current element [item], merfe the children
  let existingItem;

  // Using a for loop here to create a reference to the
  // existing item, so it'd update this item when childrens
  // will be merged.
  for (let index = 0; index < acc.length; index ++) {
    if (acc[index].name === item.name) {
      existingItem = acc[index];
      break;
    }
  }
  // if existingItem exists, merge children of
  // existing item and current item.
  // else push it into the accumulator
  if (existingItem) {
    existingItem.children = existingItem.children.concat(item.children);
  } else {
    acc.push (item);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: This runs unnecessary `loop` and `if` conditions inside `reduce`

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, but it is easier to understand. Once you have the steps and logic, code optimisation can be done. The idea was to make someone understand how to approach. And I already said this in my answer that there could be multiple ways to achieve this.

Comment: @adiga Can you please explain how you would refactor this code? I am currently working my way around deeply nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to group based on the `name` property in the level 1 object. You could do a simple [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like this:

```js
const input = [{"name":"level1","collapsed":true,"children":[{"name":"Level 1 item here","id":360082134191}]},{"name":"level1","collapsed":true,"children":[{"name":"level2","collapsed":true,"children":[{"name":"Level 2 item here","id":360082134751}]}]},{"name":"level1","collapsed":true,"children":[{"name":"Another level 1 item","id":360082262772}]}]
  
const merged = input.reduce((r,{name, collapsed, children}) =>{
    r[name] = r[name] || {name, collapsed, children:[]};
    r[name]["children"].push(...children)
    return r;
}, {})
  
const final = Object.values(merged);
console.log(final)
```

You could do the whole thing in one line:

```js
const input = [{"name":"level1","collapsed":true,"children":[{"name":"Level 1 item here","id":360082134191}]},{"name":"level1","collapsed":true,"children":[{"name":"level2","collapsed":true,"children":[{"name":"Level 2 item here","id":360082134751}]}]},{"name":"level1","collapsed":true,"children":[{"name":"Another level 1 item","id":360082262772}]}]

const output = Object.values(input.reduce((r,{name,collapsed,children}) => (
    (r[name] = r[name] || {name,collapsed,children: []})["children"].push(...children), r), {}))
console.log(output)
```